# How can I track a user for which an OTP is entered?

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

I am making a registration system in php, where after all the details are provided for registration, a request is sent to the backend, which then generates an OTP and sends a response to the client's phone, now when the OTP is entered and submitted, how does the backend recognize that the provided OTP is for which user?

I specifically DON't want to create session and send a token with the OTP request, which the client can again send back with OTP to verify which user. I don't want to have sessions for users who are not validated yet.

I was thinking of sending a cookie to the front end with the id of the newly created user, I am using ZendFramework, and I was setting the cookie to the response as: `$this->getResponse()->setRawHeader($cookie);` where $cookie is a single cookie, but somehow it's not showing in POSTMAN cookies, even though I have enabled the interceptor. And then I'm not sure, whether this is a right way to do it.

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: After user enter the OTP what will happen? Can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can keep that unique OTP in db along with the status "activated", so once the user enter that OPT you can compare with that OTP in db.If matches you can change the status of User activated.